# Setting up routing between 2 subnets

Tags: networking, router, lan, switch

I have just bought a D-Link DGS-1510-28P smart switch and I can't figure out how to set up routing on it.
It's probably a very simple issue but I guess I'm missing something:/

Here is the situation:

I have connected the D-Link to my WiFi router (Linksys WRT 1900 ACS) that has 192.168.1.1. The Linksys is working fine.
I want the all PCs that I connect to the D-Link to be in the 192.168.2.xxx subnet, so I set up the D-Link in the following way:

```
IP: 192.168.2.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

I also set up the D-Link to act as DHCP server, giving out IPs in the range from 192.168.2.10 to 192.168.2.100

The DHCP works fine, all devices connected to the D-Link get a .2 address, and they can ping each other.
So far so good.

The problem:

I cannot reach the 192.168.1.1 Linksys router from any of the PCs in the .2 range. Also pinging it from the D-Link itself doesn't work.
The cable is fine, it is properly connected, and I've tried different ports on the D-Link.

What could be the case here?

- do I need to configure the port that connects to the Linksys in a special way?
  (I know that some switches/routers have dedicated 'WAN' ports)
- am I missing something else?

Any help is more than wanted!

---

DHCP server settings on the D-Link:

```
IP 192.168.2.0 
Netmask 255.255.255.0 
Default router 192.168.2.1
```

Static routes on the D-Link:

```
IP 0.0.0.0
Mask 0.0.0.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

(this is created by the setup wizard)

Comment: Could you show the "DHCP server" settings on the D-Link? Which port did you use to connect it to the WRT router? What's the IP address of the D-Link on the 192.168.1.x subnet?

Comment: you're trying to define a default gateway outside of the host's own subnet. That is not possible, you'll have to set the default gateway to 192.168.2.1 and define a static route towards the .1 network.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In the D-Link setup UI you enter a gateway, this creates a static route from 0.0.0.0 to that gateway (192.168.1.1 in my case). This is the gateway I mentioned. 

DHCP server settings on the D-Link: 
IP 192.168.2.0
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Default router 192.168.2.1

So through DHCP my connected PCs get a gateway: 192.168.2.1

Comment: @user1686: I'm using regular LAN ports on both sides. 
Not sure I understand your last question... How can I give the D-Link a different address on the 1.x subnet?

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to configure the port that connects to the Linksys in a special way? (I know that some switches/routers have dedicated 'WAN' ports)

That's part of it, yes.

1. A router's ports belonging to different subnets are isolated from each other at layer2 (the opposite of what a switch does). Primarily, what makes the dedicated 'WAN' port in home routers "special" is that this port is *not* a part of the 'LAN' switch that joins the other ports together.

   In a switch such as yours, 802.1Q VLANs can be used to achieve this kind of isolation – if you haven't already, you should move the Linksys-facing port to a separate VLAN ID from the remaining ports, so that it'll be functionally a separate Ethernet network. (Many home routers also just use VLANs behind the scenes.)
2. Importantly, also, *each* interface in a router has its own IP configuration. You don't just assign an IP address to the router as a whole – even on a basic home router, the "LAN" interface gets an address from the LAN subnet, while the "WAN" interface gets an address from the ISP's WAN subnet.

   Your D-Link "router" needs the same as well – according to [the manual](https://www.use-ip.co.uk/datasheets/d-linkDGS-1510-28P_User_Manual.pdf#page=143), the newly created VLAN should now have its own entry in the "L3 Features > IPv4 Interface" section. Because the VLAN is connected to the 192.168.1.x network of the Linksys, it should get assigned an 192.168.1.x address. (Using DHCP is okay as long as the Linksys can offer a static lease or a "reservation".)
3. After that, the most likely remaining problem with lack of connectivity will be that 192.168.1.1 simply has no route back to the 192.168.2.x addresses that are trying to contact it, so although it receives the packets, it doesn't know how to send replies in the right direction.

   If you look at the routing table of the Linksys, you'll see that it only knows routes for networks that it is *directly* connected to, while everything else – including packets meant for 192.168.2.x – gets routed towards your ISP and there discarded.

   To make this work, start by adding a static route on the WRT, routing the new subnet via the D-Link (specifically, via the D-Link's 192.168.**1**.x address that you assigned in step 2).

   More advanced routers can exchange routes automatically using OSPF, IS-IS, or at least RIP. However, your D-Link switch doesn't support any dynamic routing protocols; it's really built to primarily be a switch with some routing on the side. (It would be marketed as a "L3 switch" if it had advanced routing features.)

Comment: You write "A router's ports belonging to different subnets are isolated from each other at layer2" <-- Layer 2 has nothing to do with subnets. Do you mean Layer 3?

Comment: @barlop: No, I specifically mean layer 2. (Subnets are not isolated at layer 3 – the very job of a router is to connect them at L3.) Having multiple IP subnets on a shared layer-2 broadcast domain is possible but problematic (e.g. broadcasts are visible by all hosts which is usually unwanted, especially with DHCP) so it's avoided whenever possible.

Comment: So by isolated you mean not able to communicate with each other.   And yeah if only layer 2 were used, so , no routing, then two subnets couldn't communicate. Speaking of a layer isolating parts of a network is a bit strange 'cos layer 2 doesn't prevent there being a layer 3.  A router could truly isolate a subnet by not routing to/from it.

Comment: also btw, switches are sometimes described as segmenting a network into isolated broadcast domains.. 'cos broadcast domains are at least a layer 2 concept .  And granted you'd often have a 1:1 relationship between broadcast domain and subnet.  Technically you could perhaps reasonably have many switches on a subnet.  So then there isn't a 1:1 between broadcast domains and subnets.

Comment: @barlop: No, switches primarily segment a network into L1 _collision_ domains, while VLANs are the usual way to segment L2 broadcast domains. An ethernet subnet (assuming no VLANs or such) is still one large broadcast domain whether it's switched or not – because a L2 broadcast frame still literally travels to every host, even through a switch. (With a hub or with old "bus" Ethernet, the entire network is one big broadcast domain _and_ collision domain; with switched Ethernet, the entire network is still one big broadcast domain but each cable is now its own collision domain.)

Comment: @barlop: It's completely normal for a broadcast domain to span multiple switches (sometimes dozens), but one broadcast domain _usually_ corresponds to one IP subnet, as it literally defines how far ARP queries can travel, so it has to match IP's idea of when ARP queries should be sent... Several IP subnets can share a broadcast domain, but it's usually avoided (issues such as broadcast leaks across subnets); a single IP subnet can _kind of_ be split across broadcast domains with help of proxy-ARP, but that's usually avoided even more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive explanation! I managed to get it working now!

Comment: @user1686 yes that makes sense that a broadcast domains would span multiple switches.. I am not  sure about this statement of yours that  "A router's ports belonging to different subnets are isolated from each other at layer2"   What do you mean by isolated? And what kind of communication can happen at just layer 2?    Presumably there are some purely layer 1 protocols.. But I don't think there are any protocols that are just layer 2 or just layers 1 and 2.  In an ARP packet there is a field for IP Address.  ARP isn't considered layer 3 but it's considered to be a link between Layers 2 and 3.

Comment: @user1686 what I do see is that if in one subnet and just using layers 1,2 or ARP,  you can't get to another subnet. To get to another subnet one would have to go through layer 3. (routing).  The phrase "isolated at layer 2" grates a bit to me, though I see you now the term exists, it gets a bunch of google results.

Comment: @barlop: Isolated in the sense that there's no *direct* path for an arbitrary L2 frame from one subnet to reach another subnet – that is, you can't just specify the destination MAC of a device on another network and have it delivered as-is through a router. (You always have to address the L2 frame to the router itself, which *consumes* the L2 frame, acts on the L3 header if it's one that the router recognizes, and generates a brand new L2 frame on the output side with only the payload being retained.)

Comment: @barlop: (The same can be seen one layer down, with switches providing L1 isolation for lack of a better term – L2 frames are forwarded between ports but there's no direct path for L1 electric or optical signals from port to port; the L1 signal is consumed and reconstructed.) Maybe a better way to describe it would be that routers aren't _transparent_ at L2, but that doesn't quite fit the main post here (i.e. doesn't make the point I'm trying to make)

Comment: @user1686 yeah I see a layer n device provides isolation for each layer n-1 function between each of the layer n device's ports.